# Выбор чекбоксов, не представленных на экране

Tags: pywinauto

Суть в следующем. Есть некий компонент (например, ListView), в котором каждый элемент списка представлен строкой и чекбоксом. Нужно отметить все чекбоксы в этом списке. Компонента вертикального скролла нет, но список можно скроллить с помощью колеса мыши.

Вот так получается выбрать первые 5 чекбоксов:

```
ITEM_COUNT = 5

for cb in range(1, ITEM_COUNT + 1):
    cb_name = 'CheckBox' + str(cb)
    check_box = wnd.child_window(best_match=cb_name, visible_only=False)
    check_box.click_input()
```

т.к. дамп элементов выдает только те чекбоксы, которые видимы на экране.
Как добраться до остальных чекбоксов и выделить их?

Пробовал прокручивать список программно, прокручивая вниз после выделения каждых двух чекбоксов:

```
for cb in range(1, ITEM_COUNT + 1):
    cb_name = 'CheckBox' + str(cb)
    check_box = wnd.child_window(best_match=cb_name, visible_only=False)
    check_box.click_input()
    if cb % 2 == 0:
        check_box.set_focus()
        mouse.scroll(coords=(400,500), wheel_dist=-2)
```

В результате - выбирает штук 10 чекбоксов, потом 2 пропускает, выделяет еще 2 и окно приложения теряет фокус (видимо, глюк).

В идеале, конечно, если бы можно было каким то одним методом выделять все чекбоксы в этом списке, даже те, которые невидимы на экране.

Comment: А какой backend используете? Если "uia", то там есть такая штука как VirtualizedItem, которые можно развиртуализировать в реальные специальным прихватом из MS UI Automation API. Тогда может получится даже прокручивать именно к нужному элементу, где бы он ни был. Но для этого хорошо бы иметь скриншот из `Inspect.exe` в режиме "UI Automation", чтобы увидеть, поддерживается VirtualizedItemPattern (если правильно помню, он так называется). Скриншот из `Inspect.exe` хорошо бы и для чек бокса и для всего ListView.

Comment: Использую как раз в режиме uia. Но при нажатии на чекбокс inspect.exe выдает инфу только об этом одном чекбоксе. А вот весь ListView выделить что-то пока не получается. Там есть "IsVirtualizedItemPatternAvailable", установлено в "false".

Comment: Ну, можно сделать Show hierarchy и выделить весь ListView в иерархии, не обязательно мышкой на него наводить. Интересно также, видит ли он свои айтемы как children или только они его как родителя (такое часто бывает с тулбаром, но вдруг и здесь).